# Google Chrome - vanity url being hit multiple times

Tags: java, javascript, google-chrome, vanity-url

I have a vanity url such as 

`www.mycompanyname-survey.com`

which does a redirect to 

`www.mycompanyname-survey.com/survey/page1`

If I submit data on the first page, it then goes to `www.mycompanyname-survey.com/survey/page2`.  However, when I do this Chrome, I see that each time I submit data to my server, it is also hitting the vanity domain `www.mycompanyname-survey.com` as well.  (I don't see this from my Chrome network traffic, but my servers network traffic.)

When I use Firefox, it's not hitting the base vanity domain.  Is there some reason Chrome is doing this and anyway to stop it?

Comment: I'm seeing this on all chrome browsers - anyone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was happening because I had no favicon defined and so Chrome was redirecting to the base domain.